# Drag div with dynamic width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**Requirements**
I am trying to create some designing tool similar to Figma. Goal is to draw a box and then drag it on parent div. I need to use this method in ReactJs but as of now I am trying in JS

Currently, I have parent div with fixed width. Now when I move child div then parent div width and height should increase dynamically. User can drag it without any limit. If user drag outside of parent div then it should auto increase width and drag div accordingly.

**Current Solution**
I create got some script to drag and drop using JS.

Till now, when user drag div to right end of parent div then I increase parent div width and auto scroll to right end.

**Issues**

- Its not scrolling right end properly. Also drag is not smooth.
- Current solution work when I move mouse but I need to auto increase width and drag box if user drag outside of parent div.

**Code**

```js
function $(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
var isDragging = true;
let isOffsetLimit = false;
var tzdragg = function(){
    return {
        move : function(divid,xpos,ypos){
            if(!isDragging) return false;
            // Stop drag if user release mouse key
            window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
                // console.log('window mouseup');
                    // do logic here
                    isDragging = false;
                    isOffsetLimit = false;
            })

            var a = $(divid);
            $(divid).style.left = xpos + 'px';
            $(divid).style.top = ypos + 'px';
            var elemParent = document.getElementById('parent');

            let evt = window.event;
            if(!evt) return;
            var posX = evt.clientX,
                posY = evt.clientY,
                a = $('elem'),
            divTop = a.style.top,
            divLeft = a.style.left;
            
            divTop = divTop.replace('px','');
            divLeft = divLeft.replace('px','');
            var diffX = posX - divLeft,
                diffY = posY - divTop;
            var posX = evt.clientX,
                    posY = evt.clientY,
                    aX = posX - diffX,
                    aY = posY - diffY;
            var boun=document.getElementById("parent").offsetWidth;

            // If user drag to right end of parent div then increase div and drag div
            if((aX>0)&&(aX>=boun-100)){
                // console.log(aX, aY, boun, isOffsetLimit);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    if(isOffsetLimit){
                        var elemParent = document.getElementById('parent');
                        const offsetWidth = elemParent.offsetWidth;
                        elemParent.style.width = offsetWidth + 10 + "px";
                        scrollRight(60);
                        tzdragg.move('elem',boun,aY);
                        // console.log('auto move', isDragging);
                    }else{
                        var elemParent = document.getElementById('parent');
                        const offsetWidth = elemParent.offsetWidth;
                        elemParent.style.width = offsetWidth + 10 + "px";
                        scrollRight(60);
                        tzdragg.move('elem',boun,aY);
                    }
                },10)
                // console.log('pos', document.getElementById("parent").offsetWidth - document.getElementById("elem").offsetWidth )
            }
        },
        setDragging : function() {
            // console.log('set drag', isDragging);
            // isDragging = true;
        },
        resetDragging : function() {
            // console.log('reset drag', isDragging);
            if(isDragging){
                // isDragging = false;
            }
        },
        startMoving : function(evt){
            // console.log('start drag', isDragging, isOffsetLimit);
            // if(!isDragging) return false;
            isDragging = true;
            evt = evt || window.event;
            var posX = evt.clientX,
                posY = evt.clientY,
                a = $('elem'),
            divTop = a.style.top,
            divLeft = a.style.left;
            
            divTop = divTop.replace('px','');
            divLeft = divLeft.replace('px','');
            var diffX = posX - divLeft,
                diffY = posY - divTop;
            document.onmousemove = function(evt){
                // isOffsetLimit = false;
                if(!isDragging) return false;
                evt = evt || window.event;
                // console.log('mouse move', isDragging);
                var posX = evt.clientX,
                    posY = evt.clientY,
                    aX = posX - diffX,
                    aY = posY - diffY;
                var boun=document.getElementById("parent").offsetWidth;
               
                if((aX>0)&&(aX<boun)&&(aY>0)&&(aY<boun)){
                    if(isOffsetLimit){
                        var elemParent = document.getElementById('parent');
                        const offsetWidth = elemParent.offsetWidth;
                        elemParent.style.width = offsetWidth + 10 + "px";
                        tzdragg.move('elem',boun+50,aY,isOffsetLimit);
                        scrollRight(60);
                        // isOffsetLimit = false;
                    }else{
                        // isOffsetLimit = false;
                        tzdragg.move('elem',aX,aY,isOffsetLimit);
                    }
                    // console.log('pos', document.getElementById("parent").offsetWidth - document.getElementById("elem").offsetWidth )
                }else{
                    // console.log('border drag', isOffsetLimit);
                    // console.log('elem', boun, aY, document.getElementById("parent").offsetWidth, document.getElementById("elem").offsetWidth);
                    var elemParent = document.getElementById('parent');
                    if(!isOffsetLimit)
                        isOffsetLimit = true;
                    const offsetWidth = elemParent.offsetWidth;
                    tzdragg.move('elem', boun, aY,isOffsetLimit);
                    elemParent.style.width = offsetWidth + 10 + "px";
                    var boun=document.getElementById("parent").offsetWidth-document.getElementById("elem").offsetWidth;
                    scrollRight(60);
                }
            }
        },
        stopMoving : function(){
            console.log('stop drag', isDragging);
            var a = document.createElement('script');
            document.onmousemove = function(){}
            isDragging = false;
            if(!isDragging) {
                // console.log('clicked');
                // scrollRight();
            }
        },
        customMove : function(evt){
            console.log('custom drag', isDragging);
            evt = evt || window.event;
            var posX = evt.clientX,
                posY = evt.clientY,
                a = $('elem'),
            divTop = a.style.top,
            divLeft = a.style.left;
            
            divTop = divTop.replace('px','');
            divLeft = divLeft.replace('px','');
            var diffX = posX - divLeft,
                diffY = posY - divTop;

            var posX = evt.clientX,
                    posY = evt.clientY,
                    aX = posX - diffX,
                    aY = posY - diffY;
            var boun=document.getElementById("parent").offsetWidth-document.getElementById("elem").offsetWidth;
            tzdragg.move('elem',aX,aY);
            document.onmousemove = function(evt){
                return false;
                evt = evt || window.event;
                console.log('custom mouse move', isDragging);
                var posX = evt.clientX,
                    posY = evt.clientY,
                    aX = posX - diffX,
                    aY = posY - diffY;
                var boun=document.getElementById("parent").offsetWidth-document.getElementById("elem").offsetWidth;
               
                if((aX>0)&&(aX<boun)&&(aY>0)&&(aY<boun)){
                    tzdragg.move('elem',aX,aY);
                    var elemParent = document.getElementById('parent');
                    // scrollRight();
                }else{
                    var elemParent = document.getElementById('parent');
                    const offsetWidth = elemParent.offsetWidth;
                    elemParent.style.width = offsetWidth + 500 + "px";
                    // elem.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
                    // window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
                    tzdragg.move('elem',aX,aY);
                    scrollRight();
                }
            }
        },
    }
}();

function scrollLft() {
    const outsider = document.getElementById('parent');
    const distance = 100;
  outsider.scrollBy({
    left: -distance,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
function scrollRight(notUsingVar) {
    // console.log('clicked')
    const outsider = document.getElementById('main');
    const distance = 400;
  outsider.scrollBy({
    left: distance,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
  // tzdragg.customMove();
}
```

```css
#elem
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
#parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  #overflow-x: scroll;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 20px 0 20px 0 grey;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
}
#main{
    width: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Drag n drp</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id='parent'>
                <div id='elem' onmousedown='tzdragg.resetDragging();tzdragg.startMoving(event);' onmouseup='tzdragg.stopMoving();' onmousemove='tzdragg.setDragging();'>
                </div>
                <!-- <div id='elem' onclick="scrollRight()">
                </div> -->
            </div>
        <div>
        <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
    </body>
</html>
```